# Linear transformation with range of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xELqa.png)

What are the steps or any guidance in solving this problem?
I'm very confused

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $A$ is a 3x5 matrix. We are given that $T(v) = Av $ where $T: \mathbb{R}^5 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. The given vector $(3,2,1)^T$ being in $\mathbb{R}^3$ means that it is in the range of $T$. To find all vectors that are mapped to that vector, let $v= (v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5) $ and solve

$$ Av = (3,2,1)^T $$

Comment: How can you tell if it does not fit in the range? and how would you write it in the vector form?